Как сделать вывод json в html по нажатию на кнопки
Мне нужно что бы была информация в json на 3 товара (название, описание)
В самом html есть 3 кнопки и по нажатию на кнопку 1 выводился название товара 1 и его описание в html и так далее
КАК ЭТО РЕАЛИЗОВАТЬ НЕ ЗНАЮ. ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА


var myObject = {
  "catalogo": [{
      "id": 0,
      "name": "one",
      "description": "111"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "two",
      "description": "222"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "three",
      "description": "333"
    }
  ]
};

let name = document.getElementById('name')
let description = document.getElementById('description')

const bnt1 = document.getElementById('bnt1')
const bnt2 = document.getElementById('bnt2')
const bnt3 = document.getElementById('bnt3')
<div>
  <h1 id="name"></h1>
  <p id="description"></p>
  <div>
    <button id="bnt1">1</button>
    <button id="bnt2">2</button>
    <button id="bnt3">3</button>
  </div>
</div>




Добавьте в вопрос ваш html, json, что пробовали, что не получилось и так далее

Отдать эту задачу web-разработчику, если не бум-бум…

mikhail zhuikov, Как видишь я это и сделал

У вас json невалидный. Может это массив объектов все таки?

может массив все таки

А если не массив?

Я уже сам не знаю, но должен быть массив по сути

Массив динамический или статический? Ключ в обьекте точно есть?(просто расходится с начальным описанием и выглядит лишним). Id у элементов как то должны влиять на номер кнопки? Html разметку можно менять?

ну смотри должна быть статика, типо что я в массиве написал, так и останется. Я не знаю нужен ли ID я его написал потому что думал что ID должен к кнопке привязаться и вывести под определенным ID информацию. Допустим у меня кнопка есть (дом) в массиве есть name: дом и num: 123 и получается что он мне должен вывести текст дом и его номер. Надеюсь объяснил нормально

Самое первое решение, которое напрашивается "в лоб", это для каждой кнопки создать свой обработчик клика и в явном виде прописать, что надо выводить(захардкодить значения):


const myObject = {
  "catalogo": [
    {"id": 0, "name": "one", "description": "111"},
    {"id": 1, "name": "two", "description": "222"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "three", "description": "333"}
  ]
};

let name = document.getElementById('name')
let description = document.getElementById('description')

const bnt1 = document.getElementById('bnt1')
const bnt2 = document.getElementById('bnt2')
const bnt3 = document.getElementById('bnt3')

bnt1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  name.innerText = myObject.catalogo[0].name;
  description.innerText = myObject.catalogo[0].description;
})

bnt2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  name.innerText = myObject.catalogo[1].name;
  description.innerText = myObject.catalogo[1].description;
})

bnt3.addEventListener('click', () => {
  name.innerText = myObject.catalogo[2].name;
  description.innerText = myObject.catalogo[2].description;
})
<div>
  <h1 id="name"></h1>
  <p id="description"></p>
  <div>
    <button id="bnt1">1</button>
    <button id="bnt2">2</button>
    <button id="bnt3">3</button>
  </div>
</div>



Это довольно плохой вариант, однако в рамках обучения, "на троечку", подойдет.
Далее, "На четверочку", можно улучшить код. Мы видим в нем в явном виде дубликат кода. Вынесем обработчик клика в отдельную функцию


const myObject = {
  "catalogo": [
    {"id": 0, "name": "one", "description": "111"},
    {"id": 1, "name": "two", "description": "222"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "three", "description": "333"}
  ]
};

let name = document.getElementById('name')
let description = document.getElementById('description')

const bnt1 = document.getElementById('bnt1')
const bnt2 = document.getElementById('bnt2')
const bnt3 = document.getElementById('bnt3')

function btnClick(id) {
  name.innerText = myObject.catalogo[id].name;
  description.innerText = myObject.catalogo[id].description;
}

bnt1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  btnClick(0)
})

bnt2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  btnClick(1)
})

bnt3.addEventListener('click', () => {
  btnClick(2)
})
<div>
  <h1 id="name"></h1>
  <p id="description"></p>
  <div>
    <button id="bnt1">1</button>
    <button id="bnt2">2</button>
    <button id="bnt3">3</button>
  </div>
</div>



Однако опять же у нас есть незначительный дубликат кода и остались захардкоженные значения. Улучшаем!
Выберем все элементы button на странице и в цикле, каждой кнопке назначим обработчик, передавая событие щелчка мышки. Так же модифицируем функцию обработчик.
Будем считать, что названия кнопок это номер позиции элемента


const myObject = {
  "catalogo": [
    {"id": 0, "name": "one", "description": "111"},
    {"id": 1, "name": "two", "description": "222"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "three", "description": "333"}
  ]
};

let name = document.getElementById('name')
let description = document.getElementById('description')

function btnClickC(event) {
  const id = +event.target.innerText -1;
  name.innerText = myObject.catalogo[id].name;
  description.innerText = myObject.catalogo[id].description;
}

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', btnClickC)
});
<div>
  <h1 id="name"></h1>
  <p id="description"></p>
  <div>
    <button id="bnt1">1</button>
    <button id="bnt2">2</button>
    <button id="bnt3">3</button>
  </div>
</div>



Ну или можно воспользоваться bind и передавать в this индекс кнопки


const myObject = {
  "catalogo": [
    {"id": 0, "name": "one", "description": "111"},
    {"id": 1, "name": "two", "description": "222"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "three", "description": "333"}
  ]
};

let name = document.getElementById('name')
let description = document.getElementById('description')

function btnClickU() {
  name.innerText = myObject.catalogo[this].name;
  description.innerText = myObject.catalogo[this].description;
}

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', btnClickU.bind(index))
});
<div>
  <h1 id="name"></h1>
  <p id="description"></p>
  <div>
    <button id="bnt1">1</button>
    <button id="bnt2">2</button>
    <button id="bnt3">3</button>
  </div>
</div>



Наверное самый правильный вариант, это создавать кнопки под каждый элемент массива:


const myObject = {
  "catalogo": [
    {"id": 0, "name": "one", "description": "111"},
    {"id": 1, "name": "two", "description": "222"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "three", "description": "333"}
  ]
};

let name = document.getElementById('name')
let description = document.getElementById('description')

const container = document.getElementById('btnCont');

myObject.catalogo.forEach((elem, index) => {
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerText = elem.id + 1;
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    name.innerText = elem.name;
    description.innerText = elem.description;
  })
  container.appendChild(btn);
})
<div>
  <h1 id="name"></h1>
  <p id="description"></p>
  <div id='btnCont'></div>
</div>



В таком случае, при изменении количества элементов в массиве, править код не надо будет

спасибо за качественный разбор. Очень благодарен
